# Scrape data hosted on AWS S3

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data offered in the public domain but hosted on AWS S3: the link is [here](https://dl.ncsbe.gov/index.html?prefix=data/SampleBallots/). The page source does not carry much, so the usual

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://dl.ncsbe.gov/index.html?prefix=data/SampleBallots/2018-11-06/"
read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("a")
```

will return nothing. By inspecting Elements, I have also tried

```
read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="listing"]/pre/a[1]')
```

but no luck either.

My best bet was open Firefox, click `ctrl + A`, and right-click and ask for `View Selection Source`, which then I parsed for `a` nodes with some regex. But the method is quite ad hoc specially in a setup with more complicated subfolder structures.

I would like to ultimately be able to download everything in the link without manual intervention, including items in all subfolders. Is there a clever method in R to tackle data on AWS S3 that I am missing?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`aws.s3`](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to download that entire bucket which is `public`, then you can use the `AWS CLI` as below.

### First locate which Bucket it is referring to:

Open the link in your browser and see the `source` which shows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var S3BL_IGNORE_PATH = true;
    var BUCKET_NAME = 'dl.ncsbe.gov';
    var BUCKET_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com';
    var S3B_ROOT_DIR = '';
</script>
```

So the bucketname is **dl.ncsbe.gov**.
Install the AWS CLI from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Now, you can download the entire bucket as below:

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://dl.ncsbe.gov .
```

This will download to your current directory

It is a large bucket, so I stopped it.
Below is what I got:

```
$ ls -lrt
total 56
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:30 Campaign_Finance
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:30 Changed_Statutes
drwxrwxr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:30 Elections
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:30 Ethics
drwxrwxr-x 11 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:30 One-Stop_Early_Voting
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:30 Outreach
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:30 PrecinctMaps
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:31 Press
drwxrwxr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:31 Public_Records_Requests
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:31 Requests
drwxrwxr-x 64 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:31 ENRS
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:31 Rulemaking
drwxrwxr-x  6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:31 NVRA
drwxrwxr-x 11 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May  5 14:31 ShapeFiles
```

If you want a specific folder and not the entire bucket, then you can add that foldername also in the `aws s3` command like:

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://dl.ncsbe.gov/data/SampleBallots/ .
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although not R it is intuitive and it works well---thank you. One question: what would be the minimal IAM permission boundary for this kind of a job? I did it using a keypair with `AdministratorAccess` policy, but I'm pretty sure that's not best security practice. Would it be `AmazonS3FullAccess`, or `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess`, or something else?

Comment: Since it is a public bucket, you should need only read-only access

Answer (score 1):

The page seems to use javascript to include the data you are looking for, see https://dl.ncsbe.gov/list.js, which is sourced upon loading the page.

Pages that make use of javascript to load the data are not supported by `rvest`, so you might have to switch to `R` + `PhantomJS` or you could do it with `RSelenium`:

The xpath you used was very close, you could remove the indexing `a[1]` otherwise you just get the first element. So i suggest using: `//*[@id="listing"]/pre/a`.

Then you can extract the links by extracting the `href` attribute and use the links in `download.file()`. I added an example for ten links with `RSelenium`. Here is a great link to set up the package: https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker.

**Reproducible example:**

```
n <- 11:20 # test for 10 links
remDr$navigate("https://dl.ncsbe.gov/index.html?prefix=data/SampleBallots/2018-11-06/")
elems <- remDr$findElements("xpath",  '//*[@id="listing"]/pre/a')
links <- unlist(sapply(elems[n], function(elem) elem$getElementAttribute("href")))

download <- function(link){
  splitted <- unlist(strsplit(link, "/"))
  fileName <- splitted[length(splitted)]
  download.file(url = link, destfile = fileName)
}
sapply(links, download)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`aws.s3`](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) package gives you easy access in R to the AWS S3 command line tools. It has helper functions to find public buckets like this one, and list the objects in a bucket.

I'll get a list of everything in that bucket within the subfolder you pointed to (`data/SampleBallots`). The default is to limit to 1000 records, which I overrode with `max = Inf`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(aws.s3)

ballot_keys <- get_bucket_df(bucket = "dl.ncsbe.gov", prefix = "data/SampleBallots", max = Inf) %>% 
  pull(Key)

length(ballot_keys)
#> [1] 10869
```

Maybe you *do* want all 10,869 objects in that folder. The keys come back as paths to each object, several of which are the zip files in the base `SampleBallots`.

```r
ballot_keys[1:4]
#> [1] "data/SampleBallots/2008-05-06.zip" "data/SampleBallots/2008-06-24.zip"
#> [3] "data/SampleBallots/2008-11-04.zip" "data/SampleBallots/2009-09-15.zip"
length(str_subset(ballot_keys, "\\.zip$"))
#> [1] 24
```

Many more files are in those subfolders you mentioned, which I haven't combed through but which have keys like this one.

```r
ballot_keys[200]
#> [1] "data/SampleBallots/2016-03-15/ANSON/ANSON-20160315-Style044-DEM-WADESBORO_1.pdf"
```

You could then use the package's `save_object` function to download whichever files you want. You could do that with just a subset of keys, like below, and some means of looping, an `*apply` function, or `purrr::map`/`purrr::walk`. Give each object a file path—I'm doing this by just taking the end of the key—and they'll download to the path you supply. I haven't downloaded more than 1 of these, because they're relatively large (~200MB).

```r
str_subset(ballot_keys, "\\.zip$") %>%
  walk(function(key) {
    filename <- str_extract(key, "[\\d\\-]+\\.zip$")
    save_object(object = key, bucket = "dl.ncsbe.gov", file = filename)
  })
```

Comment: Hi @camille, your answer sounds most like what I was going for, but at the moment I'm getting the `Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : Forbidden (HTTP 403).` Looks like it didn't happen to you, not sure why...

Comment: I'm not sure. Any chance you're behind a firewall? I've run it on two wifi networks with no issue

Comment: Ah, I think I now know what the issue is: from `bucketlist()` I get that `Your account is not signed up for the S3 service. You must sign up before you can use S3.`, whereas AWS CLI does not seem to require it---not sure why the extra step. Thank you camille.

Comment: Not sure, since this is a public bucket. I don't know that you need any type of credentials—as far as I can tell, I don't have any